# App crashes after making a signed APK?

Tags: android, crash, apk

I have an app that runs absolutely fine when I build it using the debug keystore. For the first time, I made a signed APK for release on Google PlayStore. I transferred the signed apk to my phone via the USB cable, installed the app and now when I try to run it, it crashes. It crashes right when I try to open it.

I have crash reporting enabled via Crashlytics and that doesn't report any new crashes either.

When I build it from Eclipse and run it, it all runs fine.

Where do I look for the problem?

Logcat when the app crashes:

```
07-16 01:23:28.200: E/ActivityThread(28536): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-16 01:23:28.200: E/ActivityThread(28536): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
```

Comment: You can still plug it in to the PC and read the LogCat results to see where the error is occurring.  What does it tell you?

Comment: @JaySnayder Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765588/proguard-cannot-find-referenced-libraries/24765921#24765921 Could they be related?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? Sometimes this solves my crash upon start after exporting the project.

Comment: @TheNomad My Eclipse does not crash. The **app on my phone** crashes.

Comment: @LittleChild I wouldn't think that anything would be crash related to ProGuard warnings from your other link.  Proguard as I have understood it is just merely compressing and obfuscating, so anything that it couldn't work in would just remain as it is.

Comment: @LittleChild That is what I was referring to. I had the same problem where it would crash when I used a signed APK, but would be completely fine running it off Eclipse.

Comment: @TheNomad Please wait while I clean the  project and re-export the signed APK

Comment: I can't recall if the Facebook stuff requires a specific registered key to operate in the manifest much like the Google APIs did for the maps, etc.  If you are missing this it might have worked in debug mode but wouldn't work on release.

Comment: @JaySnayder I re-made a key for Google Maps v2 using the SHA1 of my `release.keystore`. Could that be causing the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695479/regenerate-a-new-keyhash-and-key-cert-after-release

Comment: @LittleChild It could be something related to that, although its been a while since I have mingled with those keys and they intricacies.  Unfortunately I'm out the door for the day, but Good Luck Little Child.  Hopefully you find it.

Comment: @JaySnayder Check my answer. It works now. I would have been lost had you not told me that I can read logs when I plug in the phone without running the app from Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue was that ProGuard could not find certain annotations for Parse library. I had to add the following line to get it to work:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you made your signed apk with eclipse? You've probably used **proguard** unintentionally. Try to make it again but pay attention to checkboxes.

Comment: I haven't used `ProGuard` unintentionally. I have used it for a purpose :) It was a `ProGuard` configuration issue